# Google Tag Manager trigger exception doesn't work as explained in the documentation

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In below page it is explained how to use Triggers and Trigger Exceptions:

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679318?hl=en

Just like the example on the above page, I added a Tag with "Page View" track type and with an "All Pages" Trigger. Then I wanted to exclude some page titles so I made a Trigger like the below one and added it as Exception:

- Type: Page View
- Trigger on : Some page views
- Rule : PageTitle contain XXX - XXXX

I am completely sure that the spellings are correct but it isn't working as expected. The  XXX - XXXX pages are not excluded from the page views data in Google Analytics.

However when I change the rule to this:

- PageTitle does not contain XXX - XXXX

Surprisingly it is working and excluding XXX - XXXX pages. But it is evidently against the explanation of exceptions in the documentation. It is very confusing for me, I'm wondering if there is some hidden rule that I am missing. As I said I found the solution to make it works, I just want an explanation of why my solution is exactly the opposite of the Google documentation.

For what it's worth, I am working on a SPA project and XXX - XXXX is the title of the index.html of the project that I want to exclude.

Comment: Try to check in debug mode your PageTitle custom variable value exactly on "Page View" event. Maybe somehow PageTitle variable store "Undefined" value or some other strange value. Or maybe document.title value is not set yet when you're sending pageview (for example when <title> is far down in html/head code and your GTM code is just on top)

Comment: I would second the suggestion to always debug with the previewer. It gives a lot of so very useful context. I'd like to note here that an SPA won't issue pageviews on page navigations. So your pageview trigger will not fire on SPA nav. Consider using history change trigger for it.